# how to convert class in scala into Algebraic Data Types?

Tags: scala

Currently I have two classes, how to transfer them to Algebraic Data Types? I think I can do something like this `case class BlacklistDynamoDBUpdate(ruleName: String, whitelistedAccount, featureName: String)`, but how to use those method in that class?

```
class DynamoDBUpdateBlacklist {
  private var features: Array[BlacklistDynamoDBUpdate] = _

  def getFeatures = features

  def setFeatures(features: Array[BlacklistDynamoDBUpdate]) = {
    this.features = features
  }
}
```

```
class BlacklistDynamoDBUpdate {
  private var ruleName: String = _
  private var whitelistedAccount: String = _
  private var featureName: String = _

  def getFeatureName: String = featureName

  def setFeatureName(featureName: String) = {
    this.featureName = featureName
  }

  def getRuleName: String = ruleName

  def setRuleName(ruleName: String) = {
    this.ruleName = ruleName
  }

  def getWhitelistedAccounts: String = whitelistedAccount

  def setWhitelistedAccounts(whitelistedAccount: String): Unit = {
    this.whitelistedAccount = whitelistedAccount
  }
}
```

I transfer a json into scala object, json look like this

```
"features": [ { "featureName": "***", "ruleName": "***", "whitelistedAccounts": "***" }],
```

what I want is get those attributes value

Comment: To be honest I don't understand what You need. Such getters and setters are rather not popular in scala also (not big deal nevertheless). Please specify better what do you expect.

Comment: I transfer a json into scala object, json look like this ```"features": [
{
"featureName": "***",
"ruleName": "***",
"whitelistedAccounts": "***"
},
```
what I want is get those attributes value

Comment: @alexx Let me please clarify couple things: I don't see type class in your code, `DynamoDBUpdateBlacklist ` - is not. Please, read more about ad-hoc polymorphysm. Another question: Have you tried simple case class and JSON library like circe?

Comment: Still don't understand but: If you need to parse json into idiomatic scala code then use simple case classes `case class BlacklistItem(featureName:String, ruleName:String, whitelistedAccounts:String)` and library that is design to parse such jsons directly into those case classes (personally I sugest this one http://www.lihaoyi.com/upickle/ or this one https://circe.github.io/circe/).

Comment: @Scalway @ Ivan Kurchenko, I will use simple case class for that, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to parse json into idiomatic scala code then use simple case classes and library that is design to parse such jsons directly into those case classes (personally I sugest this one https://lihaoyi.com/upickle or this one https://circe.github.io/circe).

here is example code that shows how to use upickle.

```scala
import upickle.default.{ReadWriter => RW, macroRW}

final case class DynamoDBUpdateBlacklist(features:Seq[BlacklistDynamoDBUpdate])
final case class BlacklistDynamoDBUpdate(featureName:String, ruleName:String, whitelistedAccounts:String)

object DynamoDBUpdateBlacklist {
  implicit val rw: RW[DynamoDBUpdateBlacklist] = macroRW
}
object BlacklistDynamoDBUpdate {
  implicit val rw: RW[BlacklistDynamoDBUpdate] = macroRW
}

//use it like that
import upickle.default._
println(
  read[DynamoDBUpdateBlacklist]("""
    {"features":[{ "featureName": "***", "ruleName": "***", "whitelistedAccounts": "***" }]}
  """)
)

//DynamoDBUpdateBlacklist(Vector(BlacklistDynamoDBUpdate(***,***,***)))
```

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/8eqFEfX/2